# C++ DLL - Export a class that have only virtual functions but not pure virtual

Tags: c++, dll

I'm trying to make a library that can be used with various c++ compilers.

I've read some articles that says only interfaces can be exported in a DLL properly.

But I have a question..

Header

```
class Api
{
 virtual void func();
}

dllexport Api* create();
```

Cpp

```
void func() { ... }
Api* create() { return new Api; }
```

I think this class have virtual tables so the program can know the address of functions in runtime.

And it even don't need to be inherited. It looks more simple than a interface.

Is it wrong? If it is acceptable, what is the advantage of exporting interfaces?

Comment: When you say *various c++ compilers*, what are you thinking of?

Comment: @RSahu I mean various versions of vc++ compilers.

Comment: Perhaps, if the interface is very simple.  But sooner or later, usually sooner, you'll end up putting a data member in the class.  And then the trouble starts, you can't prevent the client code from using the `new` operator.  It is not an interface.